# Misaligned labels in PGF output from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, pgf

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd

mpl.rcParams.update({
    'figure.autolayout': True,
})

df = pd.DataFrame(["one quite long phrase"]*3 + 
                  ["another"]*5 + ["a terribly long phrase"] * 2 +
                  ["another long-winded one goes on"] * 4 + 
                  ["a medium one"] * 8)

df[0].value_counts().plot.barh(figsize=(5,3)).figure.savefig("test.pgf")
```

This should produce a [fairly simple horizontal bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NODNm.png). Indeed, non-PGF output is perfectly fine. However, a simple LaTeX MWE produces [something of a monstrosity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoFvS.png): the y labels are not aligned.

The only thing I can think of would be to remove the change to the `rcParams`; this does not help and instead causes the labels to be mysteriously cropped at the same time.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\input{test.pgf}
\end{center}
\caption{Reports by sector}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What can be done to fix this?

Edit: test.pgf is as follows:

```
%% Creator: Matplotlib, PGF backend
%%
%% To include the figure in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pgf}
%%
%% Make sure the required packages are loaded in your preamble
%%   \usepackage{pgf}
%%
%% Figures using additional raster images can only be included by \input if
%% they are in the same directory as the main LaTeX file. For loading figures
%% from other directories you can use the `import` package
%%   \usepackage{import}
%%
%% and then include the figures with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pgf}
%%
%% Matplotlib used the following preamble
%%   \usepackage{fontspec}
%%   \setmainfont{DejaVuSerif.ttf}[Path=\detokenize{/home/cancellarius/Documents/travail/georgiarichards.github.io/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/}]
%%   \setsansfont{DejaVuSans.ttf}[Path=\detokenize{/home/cancellarius/Documents/travail/georgiarichards.github.io/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/}]
%%   \setmonofont{DejaVuSansMono.ttf}[Path=\detokenize{/home/cancellarius/Documents/travail/georgiarichards.github.io/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/}]
%%
\begingroup%
\makeatletter%
\begin{pgfpicture}%
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{5.000000in}{3.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{use as bounding box, clip}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.000000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{1.000000,1.000000,1.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.000000}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{5.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{5.000000in}{3.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{3.000000in}}%
\pgfpathclose%
\pgfusepath{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{1.000000,1.000000,1.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.000000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.000000}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{0.381635in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{4.850000in}{0.381635in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{4.850000in}{2.850000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{2.850000in}}%
\pgfpathclose%
\pgfusepath{fill}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{0.381635in}}{\pgfqpoint{2.268793in}{2.468365in}}%
\pgfusepath{clip}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.121569,0.466667,0.705882}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.000000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.000000}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{0.505053in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{4.741962in}{0.505053in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{4.741962in}{0.751890in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{0.751890in}}%
\pgfpathclose%
\pgfusepath{fill}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{0.381635in}}{\pgfqpoint{2.268793in}{2.468365in}}%
\pgfusepath{clip}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.121569,0.466667,0.705882}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.000000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.000000}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{0.998726in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.931679in}{0.998726in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.931679in}{1.245563in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{1.245563in}}%
\pgfpathclose%
\pgfusepath{fill}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{0.381635in}}{\pgfqpoint{2.268793in}{2.468365in}}%
\pgfusepath{clip}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.121569,0.466667,0.705882}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.000000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.000000}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{1.492399in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.661584in}{1.492399in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.661584in}{1.739236in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{1.739236in}}%
\pgfpathclose%
\pgfusepath{fill}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{0.381635in}}{\pgfqpoint{2.268793in}{2.468365in}}%
\pgfusepath{clip}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.121569,0.466667,0.705882}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.000000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.000000}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{1.986072in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.391490in}{1.986072in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.391490in}{2.232909in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{2.232909in}}%
\pgfpathclose%
\pgfusepath{fill}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{0.381635in}}{\pgfqpoint{2.268793in}{2.468365in}}%
\pgfusepath{clip}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.121569,0.466667,0.705882}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.000000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.000000}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{2.479745in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.121396in}{2.479745in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.121396in}{2.726582in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{2.726582in}}%
\pgfpathclose%
\pgfusepath{fill}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{2.581207in}{0.381635in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=2.581207in,y=0.284413in,,top]{\color{textcolor}\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 0}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{3.121396in}{0.381635in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=3.121396in,y=0.284413in,,top]{\color{textcolor}\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 2}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{3.661584in}{0.381635in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=3.661584in,y=0.284413in,,top]{\color{textcolor}\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 4}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{4.201773in}{0.381635in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=4.201773in,y=0.284413in,,top]{\color{textcolor}\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 6}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{4.741962in}{0.381635in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=4.741962in,y=0.284413in,,top]{\color{textcolor}\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 8}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{2.581207in}{0.628471in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=1.481313in, y=0.575710in, left, base]{\color{textcolor}\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont a medium one}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{2.581207in}{1.122144in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=1.940839in, y=1.069383in, left, base]{\color{textcolor}\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont another}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{2.581207in}{1.615817in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=0.150000in, y=1.563056in, left, base]{\color{textcolor}\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont another long-winded one goes on}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{2.581207in}{2.109490in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=0.962446in, y=2.056729in, left, base]{\color{textcolor}\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont one quite long phrase}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{2.581207in}{2.603163in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=0.991268in, y=2.550402in, left, base]{\color{textcolor}\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont a terribly long phrase}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{0.381635in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{2.850000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{4.850000in}{0.381635in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{4.850000in}{2.850000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{0.381635in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{4.850000in}{0.381635in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{2.581207in}{2.850000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{4.850000in}{2.850000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfpicture}%
\makeatother%
\endgroup%
```

Comment: Can you show `test.pgf`?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz good idea; I’ve added it above.

Comment: Thanks! So from the pgf side, the source of the problem is that matplotlib exports the labels anchored to the left -- so unless you have exactly the same font size as in matplotlib, the result will be a mess. Proof of concept with right aligned text: https://pastebin.com/0eKJyLQY